# Problem with Solr dynamic/copy Field

Tags: lucene, solr

I have a problem that i have a dynamic field in schema.xml

as `<dynamicField name="sec_*" type="text" indexed="true" stored="false"/>`

and `<field name="Contents" type="text" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>`

dynamic field is copied to Contents field as

```
<copyField source="sec_*" dest="Contents"/>
```

now when i perform search using some dynamic fields like "sec_1069:risk" it filters documents that does not contains that dynamic field called sec_1069 can any body help how i can force this thing that solr should not filter documents that don't have that dynamic field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `sec_1069:risk OR -sec_1069:[* TO *]`